# Close WebSocket connection on logout

Tags: reactjs, websocket, actioncable

I'm working on a React app where I have an access provider managing user authentication and authorization, and I'm also using the Action Cable library for WebSocket communication.

I'm facing an issues:

- Closing WebSocket Connection on Logout: I'm unsure about the best practice for closing the WebSocket connection when a user logs out of the app. Currently, I have an AccessProvider component that handles user authentication and a logoutUser function that gets triggered on logout. How can I properly close the WebSocket connection in this scenario?
  (I put AccessProvider inside ActioncableProvider so I can call useActioncableContext there and then disconnect when the user logs out. However, I realized that when the user is not authenticated, gets redirected to the login page, logs in... then ActioncableProvider keeps the consumer instance which is configured with the empty/invalid token)

Here's a simplified version of my code for reference:

```
// ... (other imports and code)

function AccessProvider() {
  // ... (authentication logic)

  return (
    <AccessContext.Provider value={...}>
      {/* Render ActioncableProvider only when authorized */}
      {user.isAuthorized && <ActioncableProvider />}
      <Outlet />
    </AccessContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

And an ActioncableProvider component that handles real-time updates:

```
// ... (other imports and code)

function ActioncableProvider() {
  // ... (Actioncable logic)

  return (
    <ActioncableContext.Provider value={...}>
      <Outlet />
    </ActioncableContext.Provider>
  );
}
```